# Keras Tensorflow Aggregate Metrics Using Addition Instead of Mean

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, addition

I know that Tensorflow/Keras provides stateful metrics which can be updated using `metric.update_state()`. I understand this updating of metrics in a stateful manner is performed via taking average/mean using `MeanMetricWrapper` class.

What should I do in case I would like to update the metrics using another operation for example, addition (let's say I would like to accumulate loss across all batches instead of taking the average, so I can print the loss across entire epoch instead of per-batch average).

I am more interested in solutions that can work seamlessly with `model.train_on_batch()`. Thank you.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far. Anyway, if you want to sum up losses of all batches in each epoch you just need to accumulate them like this: ``for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    acc_loss = 0.
    for batch in range(n_batches):
        # do the training 
        loss = model.train_on_batch(...)
        acc_loss += loss``

Comment: @Kaveh Thanks for your reply. This is what I am doing right now i.e., manually. I would prefer a way that is done internally/automatically by Keras using their stateful Metric classes.

Comment: Check it out: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Reduction may help you ``tf.keras.losses.Reduction.SUM``

Comment: Thanks @Kaveh. To my understanding, that function only applies for a given batch and cannot keep state across batches.